# expectation half-normal distribution or expectation Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, problem-solving

I want to calculate integrals
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty x \exp\{ ax-b x^2\} dx
   &= \int_0^\infty x\exp\{-b(x^2-\frac{a}{b}x)\}dx\\
   &= \exp\left\{\frac{a^2}{4b}\right\}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
      \int_0^\infty x \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt\pi(1/2)}
                    \exp\left(\frac{-b}{2(1/2)}\left(x-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2\right)dx
\end{split}
$$ 
Integral 
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt\pi(\frac{1}{2})}\exp\frac{-b}{2(1\2)}(x-\frac{a}{2b})^2dx$$
is a expectation half-normal distribution or expectation Truncated Normal Distribution؟ and What is the final answer?